# Empty object validation in json schema

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to validate a json using a JSON schema. 
In the below json "industry" is of type "object" and it is "not required". 
however i need to find out if "industry" is provided in the json or not.

**here is my json schema**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "enum": ["Russia", "Canada"]
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "industry": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/industry"
    }
  },
 "required": [
    "id",
    "name"
    ],
  "definitions": {
      "industry": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "codes": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "codes",
        "type"
      ],
      "title": "industry"
    }
  }
}
```

**here is my json**

```
{
  "id": "Russia",
  "price": 10.50
}
```

I want to know if "industry" object is present or not in the given json bcos if the "industry" object is present in the json. I need to do something else. currently if i send the json as above and try this if statement like below code. It is passing as true even though "industry" object is not present in the json. I believe it is considering "industry" object like this {} and not as null.

```
    "if":{
      "properties": {"industry" : {  "type": "object" }}
    },
```

Any solution to validate if the "industry" object is present in the json object or not will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A schema containing "properties" will evaluate to true if the property is not present. What you want to put as the conditional of your "if" is "required":

`"if": {"required":["industry"]}, "then": { ... }`

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. the above ans partially worked for me. but it started throwing me an error like this "required key [industry] not found" when it was time to go for "else" part + it executed the else part. when "industry" key is not present. It should not throw me an error, I just need it to execute the "else" part.